Compiling a package using flags
I have to install an R package in my linux workstation (Debian 11, kernel 5.10.0-33-amd64) using particular compilation flags but I am in trouble. From root:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-args="CXXFLAGS=-lrt" /path/to/my/package.tar.gz 

but in the compilation result I see that the flags are ignored and the package failed to install.
How can I install this package?

You should not need to set such flags to compile a package. The package itself should set the necessary flags in its configuration. Doing it manually will lead to breakage.

I need to set this flag due an install error

Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged.

@Adriaan But in addition this would not be a good answer. In fact, it will cause other breakages when installing other packages.
